# How to automate terminal inputs/commands?

Tags: shell, terminal, automation, scripting

For example, if I'm using GitLab and every time I do git pull/push etc. It shows this `Username for 'https://gitlab.example.com':` so every time this text has appeared in terminal it should automatically enter the specific input. Also on a broader scale if

I put a bunch of commands asking for input in a sh file all the respective inputs would be entered automatically by the terminal.

Git is just for example here, because there exists a way to automate git by adding ssh key. Another example is `ssh` or `scp`. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Aliases + your own scripts in your choice of language (bash, curl, perl, python, etc).

Comment: could you elaborate more?

Comment: Look into `expect`.

Comment: Tried, no luck. Still trying.